# Convert button objects to link objects in acrobat

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

I have a 40 page PDF. On each page is a Previous and Next button object. I run the PDF through a tool that converts it to a SWF. The problem is the tool I run it through doesn't know what to do with Button Objects. They are visible, just inactive. Basically they don't do anything once a SWF.

What I have to do is create an invisible link object over each button and set it to

`Execute Menu Item > View > Page Navigation > Previous Page| Next Page`

Once I do that for EVERY button object, the tool I run it through recognizes it and will change pages via the buttons once a SWF.

So my question, can I convert all button objects to link objects with some sort of script?

Answer (score 1):

if it's still up to date:

I Think you can do this with Javascript for Adobe Acrobat.
There is an Acrobat API for Javascript and for more Advanced Problems one for Plugin (And a third one but I'm also relative new to Acrobat Development), if you're interested in more information about that, you can find here:
http:// www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/overview.html

To Javascript and your question:
You have to do something like

1. Loop through all Pages and find all Buttons
2. At the place of the Buttons create link object

Hope that might push you in the right direction.
The following two links might also be helpful

1. [JavaScript for Acrobat API Reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/10/Acrobat10_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?href=JavaScript_SectionPage.70.1.html#1516232&accessible=true) 
   -> class Link and method setAction
2. [Acrobat JavaScript ScriptingGuide](http://www.verydoc.com/documents/acrojsguide/)
   -> for Acrobat 7 but might be helpful - Look on page 94 for Button